# Loopback with Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, loopbackjs, loopback, azure-storage-files

following the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#provider-credentials), I've already connected my Loopback to Azure Storage using this datasource.

```
...
"azure": {
   "name": "azure",
   "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
   "provider": "azure",
   "storageAccount": "storageAccountNamexxxx",
   "storageAccessKey": "accessKeyxxxx" 
}
...
```

and this model-config :

```
...
"container": {
  "dataSource": "azure",
  "public": true
}
...
```

Unfortunately, I encounter these following errors even though the **download & upload are working well** as expected :

- It returning an **empty array** when I want to [list all files within specified container](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#api).
- **Authentication error** when I call API to [list all containers](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#api) & if the file name being uploaded/downloaded is using space.

This is the authentication error message :

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Error>
<Code> AuthenticationFailed </Code>
   <Message>
       Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:72a99edb-b01e-002f-3cb3-b07c25000000\nTime:2019-12-12T06:18:06.6288549Z
   </Message>
   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
       The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'cZ/+6cE0mCSNA7TM7Zlh+m0SK0MdLGmRDXqA0B3Bg4c=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:18:05 GMT\nx-ms-version:2011-08-18\n/storageAccountNamexxxx/\ncomp:list'.
   </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Any suggestion how I can fix those ? thank you in advance.

Comment: make sure you pasted the entire storage key to the config

Comment: already, but only the download & upload are working